# How to move the page up each time to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am  creating a form where i have many child forms to submit,so i have used a jQuery functionality where each submit a msg will show at the top of the page ,now what i want,on each submit the page will scroll up to the div where that jQuery is calling .Here is my code

```
 var url = "<%=addPersonalDetailsURL%>";    
 var type = "addPersonalDetails";
if(!($('#<portlet:namespace/>address1').val()=='' || $('#country').val()=='None' ||$('#<portlet:namespace/>primaryPhone').val()=='')){
 jQuery.getJSON(url+"&address1="+address1+"&address2="+address2+"&country="+country+"&state="+state+"&city="+city+"&zip="+zip+"&skypeId="+skypeId+"&twitter="+twitter+"&primaryPhone="+primaryPhone+"&secondaryPhone="+secondaryPhone+"&type="+type, function(data) {


            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".success").offset().top
            }, 800);


        for(var z=0; z<data.applicationArray.length;z++){

            applicationArray = data.applicationArray[z].split("$$##$$##");

            address1 = applicationArray[0];
            address2 = applicationArray[1];
            city = applicationArray[2];
            primaryPhone = applicationArray[3];

        }
```

jQuery.getJSON is giving some result where on the basis i have to use that functionality.So can you tell how i should modify your solution

Answer (score 1):

You should need to get your element's top position in the page and move the scroll to that position. Something like the code below:

```
jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery(".success").offset().top);
```

Note that the code above will move to the first `.success` position. If you have to reference a specific one, add the index in the selector, for example:

```
jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery(".success:eq(1)").offset().top);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this function:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".whichElement").offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

Explanation:
If the button is clicked, we scroll the page to the element with class
`whichElement` and the duration of the scroll is `800ms`.

Example:

```js
$(".first-hey").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".second-hey").offset().top
    }, 800);
});

$(".second-hey").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".third-hey").offset().top
    }, 800);
});

$(".third-hey").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".first-hey").offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

```css
.divide {
    height: 1300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="first-hey">First hey</button>

<div class="divide"></div>

<button class="second-hey">Second hey</button>

<div class="divide"></div>

<button class="third-hey">Third hey</button>
```

Comment: solution was nice but i don't need to click any button to call that i am clicking  a button which is giving some result on the basis of that i want that functionality. I am showing you  how my function is working ,editing my question